# ¿Cómo mostrar una matriz en un formulario de VBA?

Tags: array, excel, vba, matrices, listbox

Estoy incursionando en VBA, para eso estoy utilizando en el modo desarrollador de excel el editor de BVA. Estoy trabajando en un UserForm y dentro del click de un botón llené una matriz (n*2), y ahora deseo mostrarla en el formulario al hacer click, para eso pensé en utilizar un ListBox o algo parecido ¿Alguien puedo ayudarme a mostrar dicho arreglo en el formulario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu array es de dos columnas puedes hacerlo así:

```
With Me.MiListbox

    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "45;150"
    .List = MiArray

End With
```